# About gRPC, undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort`

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I use gRPC for Run Code, it seems like expamples/helloworld in gRPC, but when I use it in my project, it run Error. This is Error: [Run Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCwC8.png) . This is CMakelists.txt[CMakelists.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oridu.png)
I do not konw what's the reason lead to this error. How Can I fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect code and error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as image. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your question post accordingly.

Comment: This is a clear *linker error* and is probably caused by a mistake in your CMakeLists.txt. Edit your question to show us that.

Comment: linker error, so, what files should I need to provide.